# Warnings: Why are statements with limit clause unsafe even if there isn't a limit?

Tags: mysql, replication, innodb, mysql-5.5, logs

I'm a bit irritated because of some warnings in mysql errorlog.
Example 1:

```
[Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. 
The statement is unsafe because it uses a LIMIT clause. 
This is unsafe because the set of rows included cannot be predicted. 
Statement: UPDATE `table` SET `status` = '1' WHERE `ID` = '15800' LIMIT 1
```

My colleague wrote these statements and I always wondered about the purpose of limiting a statement while using explicit ID. Nonetheless, this warning also occurs by *not* using LIMIT.
Example 2:

```
[Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. 
The statement is unsafe because it uses a LIMIT clause. 
This is unsafe because the set of rows included cannot be predicted. 
Statement: DELETE FROM table WHERE id = 426888
```

What could be wrong in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have LIMIT without ORDER BY. Therefore, it is meaningless.

Sets do not have implied orders without ORDER BY. The error message tells you this:

> This is unsafe because the set of rows included cannot be predicted

Does your DELETE have a trigger or such with a LIMIT?

Comment: We indeed had triggers set (on both update and delete) which statements also contained the limit clause. Corrected and no warning occurs anymore, thank you.

Comment: @32bitfloat: he he Gotta watch for those pesky triggers... :-)

Answer (score 2):

What scares me about this question is that MySQL does not report a problem at the trigger level in the error. I wrote about this problem before back on Jan 06, 2012 : [Has anyone ran into this replication breaking bug before?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10324/has-anyone-ran-into-this-replication-breaking-bug-before/10325#10325)

I wrote in that past post that [the bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=45677) shows that as of Dec 10, 2010, there was a problem with trigger level issues not showing up in the error log while the reported problem would appear to be the original SQL. In your case, you see `DELETE FROM table WHERE id = 426888` and just scratch your head, asking "*how in the world would such a straightforward DELETE statement be deemed unsafe*"?

MORAL OF THE STORY

[**@gbn's answer**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21686/877) helped you realize that you needed to look to your trigger (+1 for @gbn). I wanted to reveal further how MySQL dropped the ball in not properly logging errors from the trigger level.

Comment: Thanks for the background-information - as I am not that familiar with triggers, I assumed that there would in general be no possibility to get problems of trigger-queries directly reported.

Comment: +1. MySQL frightens me when I compare it to SQL Server. It has some nice stuff (say INSERT IGNORE) but otherwise some stuff is just crazy...

Comment: @gbn some known/unknown bugs linger from MySQL 4.x I don't know what worse, being MySQL Certified or being Windows Vista Certified : https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/cert-windowsclient.aspx?#tab3