# How to delete rows from the mid of the table without any where condition?

Tags: mysql, innodb, delete, where

I have a table `testing` with two columns

- `id: auto_increment`
- `name: varchar(20)`

I fired a query `select * from testing limit 1, 2` which gave me 2nd and 3rd record. Now, I want to delete these records from MySQL table (InnoDB engine). How can I achieve this?

This table I have created is just for testing purposes. My actual table contains billions of records. One way I thought as:

```
delete from testing where id in (select group_concat(id) from testing limit 1, 2);
```

I think this would be quite slow in case of my actual table.

Can anyone provide any better solution?

Comment: There is no "middle", "2nd" or "3d" record in a relational table, so your problem statement amounts to deleting two random rows from the table. Is that what you want?

Comment: N rows starting from a random row. In this example, 2 rows starting from 2nd row. It could be 2 Million rows starting from 10th row.

Comment: *"starting from the 2nd row, starting from the 10th row."* You did not understand mustaccio's comment. There is no inherent order in SQL tables. When you say "second row", second by which order do you mean? (it can `order by id`, `order by name`, `order by name desc`, etc...) **`LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` will essentially give some random results.**

Comment: Refer question once again, "I fired a query select * from testing limit 1, 2 which gave me 2nd and 3rd record. Now, I want to **delete these records**". So, Its clear that I want to delete only those records that are fetched from the select query. I think by default `order by` is applied on first column, which is an auto_increment id here. Am I clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for can lead to unpredictable results in certain situations.

What kind of situations?

1. Running this on a Master and the Slave receives the same SQL. The problem I see is that rows of data in a Master may not be physically written in the same order on the Slave.
2. Triggers will encounter issue (or really create issues) with this type of `DELETE` query

I am sure there are other situations, but these came to mind first.

I addressed these before

- `Feb 22, 2011` : [Problem with MySQL subquery](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/problem-with-mysql-subquery/1384#1384)
- `Jul 30, 2012` : [Warnings: Why are statements with limit clause unsafe even if there isn't a limit?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21685/warnings-why-are-statements-with-limit-clause-unsafe-even-if-there-isnt-a-limi/21698#21698)

## SUGGESTION

If you look back at the original question ([Problem with MySQL subquery](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/1371/877)), the OP suggested getting the key for the row you want deleted. Then issue the delete using that key. It's the safest way.

## YOUR ACTUAL QUESTION

Doing fancy DELETEs, even if possible, could produce unwantd results on Slave, on a Master, or even a Standalone DB Server when not using `WHERE`.

In the end, you must use `WHERE` for the safest and most expected results.